# Не срабатывает таймаут в функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Знания в `JavaSript` у меня не очень, много трудился чтобы написать такой сценарий:

```
/* ADD MODULE */

$('#add_module_modal').on('click', function() {

        $('#progress_content').html("<i class='fa fa-gear fa-1x fa-spin'></i>");

    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data_file = new FormData();
    form_data_file.append('file', file_data);
    var form_data = $('#module_form').serialize();

   $.ajax({
                url: 'download_modules.php',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data_file,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(){//success

                    function addModuleData(form_data){

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'download_modules.php',
                            cache: false,
                            data: form_data,
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#modal_body_module').html(data);
                                $('#progress_content').html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i>");
                            }
                        });
                    }       

                    setTimeout(addModuleData(form_data), 6000);


                }//success
     });
});

/* END ADD MODULE */
```

Данный код работает почти как нужно, т.е. загрузка самого файла происходит и вторым запросом отправляются данные с `input - ов` но второй запрос проходит следом без таймаута хотя я указал таймаут и он нужен. Как сделать так чтобы функция `addModuleData(form_data)` выполнялась с таймаутом? Также обязательно нужно передать функции параметр `form_data`. Буду рад помощи!

Comment: `setTimeout(addModuleData, 6000, form_data)`

Comment: @Yaant благодарю, работает! :)

Comment: Мой вопрос отмечен как дубликат но это не так! В том вопросе функция без передачи параметров, а в моем вопросе нужно передать именно параметр.

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры, _Мой вопрос отмечен как дубликат но это не так_ - это так. Ключевая проблема, в том что функция не передается, а вызывается. Именно об этом и идет речь в дубликате